# Why is VecDeque slower than a Vec?

Tags: rust, vector, data-structures, deque

I'm beginning to optimize performance of a crate, and I swapped out a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) for a [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html). The container maintains elements in sorted order (it's supposed to be fairly small, so I didn't yet bother trying a heap) and is occasionally split down the middle into two separate containers (another reason I haven't yet tried a heap) with `drain`.

I'd expect this second operation to be much faster: I can copy the first half of the collection out, then simply rotate and decrease the length of the original (now second) collection. However, when I run my `#[bench]` tests, performing the above operations a variable number of times, (below in million ns/iters) I observed a performance *decrease* with the `VecDeque`:

|  | test a | test b | test c | test d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vec | 12.6 | 5.9 | 5.9 | 3.8 |
| VecDeque | 13.6 | 8.9 | 7.3 | 5.8 |

A reproducible example ([gist](https://gist.github.com/LincolnAuster/b7ec0c81f4a87b6faa13d72bc1f21fcb)):

```rust
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn insert_in_sorted_order_vec<E: Ord + Eq>(t: &mut Vec<E>, k: E) {
    match t.binary_search(&k) {
        Ok(i) => t[i] = k,
        Err(i) => t.insert(i, k),
    }
}

fn insert_in_sorted_order_vecdeque<E: Ord + Eq>(t: &mut VecDeque<E>, k: E) {
    match t.binary_search(&k) {
        Ok(i) => t[i] = k,
        Err(i) => t.insert(i, k),
    }
}

fn split_vec<T>(mut t: Vec<T>) -> (Vec<T>, Vec<T>) {
    let a = t.drain(0..(t.len() / 2)).collect();
    (a, t)
}

fn split_vecdeque<T>(mut t: VecDeque<T>) -> (VecDeque<T>, VecDeque<T>) {
    let a = t.drain(0..(t.len() / 2)).collect();
    (a, t)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use test::Bencher;

    static ITERS_BEFORE_SPLIT: u32 = 50;
    static ITERS_TIME: u32 = 10_000;

    #[bench]
    fn vec_manip(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut v = Vec::new();
            for i in 0..(ITERS_TIME / ITERS_BEFORE_SPLIT) {
                for j in 1..(ITERS_BEFORE_SPLIT + 1) {
                    insert_in_sorted_order_vec(&mut v, i * j / (i + j)); // 'random'-ish illustrative number
                }

                v = split_vec(v).1;
            }
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn vecdeque_manip(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut v = VecDeque::new();
            for i in 0..(ITERS_TIME / ITERS_BEFORE_SPLIT) {
                for j in 1..(ITERS_BEFORE_SPLIT + 1) {
                    insert_in_sorted_order_vecdeque(&mut v, i * j / (i + j)); // 'random'-ish illustrative number
                }

                v = split_vecdeque(v).1;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `Vec` implementation took 69.2k ns/iter, and the `VecDeque` implementation took 91.8k.

I've repeated and verified these results a number of times - why is it that performance decreases with this more flexible data structure?

These results were obtained by running `cargo bench`.

- Linux 5.11
- 3900X (12 cores, 3.8-4.6 GHz)
- 32GB 3200 MHz RAM
- rustc 1.55.0-nightly
- default `cargo bench` options (optimized, no debug symbols as far as I can tell, etc.)

### Edit

I changed the `split_vecdeque` method to utilize `split_off` instead of `drain().collect()` (see below). It *looks* like this method is guaranteed to not reallocate or shift anything around, instead just moving the `head` and `tail` pointers around; see the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.split_off) and [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/vec_deque/mod.rs.html#1969). That, however, performs even worse than the original VecDeque at 98.2k ns/iter. For larger values (ITERS_BEFORE_SPLIT = 50_000, ITERS_TIME = 5_000_000), though performance (21.8m ns/iter) is better than `drain` (23.1 ns/iter) and worse than `Vec` (19.1 ns/iter).

```rust
fn split_vecdeque<T>(mut t: VecDeque<T>) -> (VecDeque<T>, VecDeque<T>) {
    let a = t.split_off(t.len() / 2);
    (t, a)
}
```

Comment: *why is it that performance decreases with this more flexible data structure?* - Isn't it **expected** for performance to decrease with a more flexible data structure? That is, unless you are making use of the differences between `Vec` and `VecDeque` that would work in the latter's favor - such as popping elements off the front. Since you don't appear to be doing any of that, and use `VecDeque` as if it were a `Vec`, you are paying the price of using the more complex type without reaping its benefits.

Comment: @user4815162342 I believe I *am* making use of the differences - the split operation works by rotating the buffer, rather than sliding everything backwards as in a Vec, AFAIK.

Comment: I have misread the code, then. Maybe then it's just the case of the benefits failing to outweigh the drawbacks. Have you tried increasing the size, to provoke the situation where `VecDeque` should begin to show an advantage?

Comment: @user4815162342 With larger splits, the delta looks to get smaller, but never to the point of the VecDeque becoming faster - could you expound upon the drawbacks, maybe in an answer? thanks!

Comment: I meant the general drawback of `VecDeque` being more complex to index - where `Vec` has a single pointer indirection (after a bounds check), `VecDeque` requires additional wrapping arithmetic involving the tail. Because of that I'd expect e.g. the binary search to be faster for `Vec` than for `VecDeque`. But I wouldn't want to write an actual answer before analyzing your code in detail, which I don't have the time (and possibly knowledge) for.

Comment: If `VecDeque` performed the same as `Vec` for every operation that `Vec` supports then there would be no point having both data structures. Pay for what you are use: if you aren't using the double-endedness of `VecDeque` then use a `Vec`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `VecDeque` is like a `Vec` but supports pushing and popping from both ends efficiently. In order to do this, it uses a single, contiguous buffer (just like a `Vec`), but treats it as two partitions; a head and a tail.

The structure is laid out like this:

```
pub struct VecDeque<T> {
    tail: usize,
    head: usize,
    buf: RawVec<T>,
}
```

Items in the buffer are ordered like this:

```
[[tail: 5, 6, 7] ...unused... [head: 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Adding an item to the end of the collection will append to the the tail, using some of the unused space. Adding to the start of the collection will add to the start of the head, eating into the same space. When the head and tail meet in the middle, the `VecDeque` is full and will need to reallocate.

Compared with `Vec`:

```
pub struct Vec<T> {
    buf: RawVec<T>,
    len: usize,
}
```

Which uses its buffer like this:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 ...unused...]
```

Adding an item at the end is fast, but adding an item at the start requires copying all of the existing items to make space.

Most operations on `VecDeque` are made more complicated by this layout and this will slightly reduce its performance. Even retrieving its length is more complicated:

```
pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
    count(self.tail, self.head, self.cap())
}
```

The whole point of `VecDeque` is to make *certain* operations faster, namely pushing and popping the *start* of the collection. `Vec` is very slow at this, especially if there are a lot of items, because it involves moving all of the other items to make space. The structure of `VecDeque` makes these operations fast but at the expense of performance of other operations in comparison to `Vec`.

Your tests doesn't appear to take advantage of `VecDeque`'s design, since they are dominated by calls to `insert`, which involves the expensive copying of many items in both cases.

Comment: **VecDeque vs Vec On Removing Of Elements**.
I've read this somewhere, but can't find it again as of this writing. May I ask, is this statement somewhat accurate: In a large (by large, I have no way of determining the specific value) enough sized vector, it's more efficient to execute `remove()` on a `VecDeque` than in a `Vec`, because in the latter, succeeding elements of the chosen index are all shifted to the left, whereas the former, [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.remove) happens?

Comment: Thanks one thing I wonder about is why Vec is inefficient at removing from the start of the array. I would have thought this was a case of incrementing the pointer to the start of the array forwards and freeing that mem, I don't understand why it would require any mem shifting (to either the front or back)?

Comment: @Dominic That's because of constraints imposed by the allocator. If you were to just shift the start pointer up, then you would now have a smaller allocation. Cool. But when you later free the memory, the allocator will not recognise the pointer address because it won't be the same as the one it originally gave. This will trigger undefined behaviour.

Comment: To make this sound, you'd have to then track _two_ pointers, the one it originally gave and the one that you are now using as the first item. That's extra bookkeeping overhead and - more importantly - it would make it hard to reason about memory usage.

Comment: I see thanks, making a single-threaded trading orderbook so perf is important, hopefully the safety first priority Rust takes doesn't impact perf too much

Comment: A VecDeque is a much better choice for an order book. If you used a data structure like you described, which gradually reduced it's capacity, you'd have to reallocate at some point, which would give you a noticeable latency spike. A VecDeque-based order book should be able to handle 5-10 million messages per sec on medium spec hardware. You might also consider a BTreeMap, which could give better worst-case latency when you consider order cancellations, which are typically far more common than actual trades. As always, test performance and never assume, because you'll often be surprised :)

Comment: Thanks good to know you thinks so. I’m doing the price levels as BTreeMap and the orders in each level as a VecDeque (so I can remove from the first order that was entered when filling). Yeah a BTreeMap in Rust’s implementation is an interesting twist on a classic Binary Search Tree with potentially better perf as their docs state (even with linear search) will be interesting to see how it performs